# Is there any possibility to read topic from JMS message as a consumer

Tags: jms, spring-jms, solace

Summary:

I have created a small Spring Boot application which should consume messages from a Solace instance. In Solace the publisher has maintained a queue which is subscribed to different topics.
I, as consumer, am processing the messages provided in the queue. Depending on the original topic leading to a message in this queue I would like to react differently in my business logic.
Means I need to somehow extract the topic of the message provided via the solace queue.

I have already have checked JMS header/properties, but I found nothing related to topic.

Anyone any idea or had a similar use case?

A workaround which came to my mind was to directly subscribe to all topics and create for every topic a method to consume and react accordingly, but then we would miss the queue features, or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the `Destination` and `JMSDestination` headers should contain the topic that the message was published to.

For example, to test this real quick I created a `StackOverflowQueue` queue with a topic subscription to the `this/is/a/topic` topic. And upon publishing a message to `this/is/a/topic` my consumer, which was listening to the queue, got the topic info in the header.

To quickly test I used the JMS sample here: https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-jms/blob/master/src/main/java/com/solace/samples/QueueConsumer.java

```
Awaiting message...
Message received.
Message Content:
JMSDeliveryMode:                        2
JMSDestination:                         Topic 'this/is/a/topic'
JMSExpiration:                          0
JMSPriority:                            0
JMSDeliveryCount:                       1
JMSTimestamp:                           1665667425784
JMSProperties:                          {JMS_Solace_DeliverToOne:false,JMS_Solace_DeadMsgQueueEligible:false,JMS_Solace_ElidingEligible:false,Solace_JMS_Prop_IS_Reply_Message:false,JMS_Solace_SenderId:Try-Me-Pub/solclientjs/chrome-105.0.0-OSX-10.15.7/3410903749/0001,JMSXDeliveryCount:1}
Destination:                            Topic 'this/is/a/topic'
SenderId:                               Try-Me-Pub/solclientjs/chrome-105.0.0-OSX-10.15.7/3410903749/0001
SendTimestamp:                          1665667425784 (Thu. Oct. 13 2022 09:23:45.784)
Class Of Service:                       USER_COS_1
DeliveryMode:                           PERSISTENT
Message Id:                             1
Replication Group Message ID:           rmid1:18874-bc0e45b2aa1-00000000-00000001
Binary Attachment:                      len=12
  48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f    72 6c 64 21                Hello.world!
```

Note that sample code doesn't use Spring Boot, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Correct! JmsDestination provides the topic!